# display an error message in symfony2

Tags: symfony, flush

I am new in symfony, I made a form to signup new users, the form is simple ; e-mail, name and password. I want to display an error message depending on the exception. example (username exists). My code works fine but how to catch exception and display error ???

```
public function signupAction(Request $request) {
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $username = $request->get('username');
        $firstname = $request->get('firstname');
        $password = $request->get('password');

        $user = new Users();
        $user->setFirstName($firstname);
        $user->setPassword(sha1($password));
        $user->setUserName($username);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:signup.html.twig');
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with your own FormType class as below:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password')
        ;
    }

    ...
}
```

And in your controller you would write something like this:

```
/**
 * Displays a form to create a new User entity.
 *
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new User();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("CoreBundle:User:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity     = new User();
    $form       = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a form to create a User entity.
 *
 * @param User $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(User $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}
```

And in your entity User you need to add a constraint to ensure that your username is unique:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 */
class Author{
    ...
}
```

In this way, you would render the User form with the errors if the form is not valid or the username field is used.

You can read more about constraints in http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html

I recommend to you look at FOSUserBundle if you want to manage your user accounts. https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle